# Create distance matrix for all string pairs with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, matrix, distance

I have a list that I would like to turn into a distance matrix

```
from pylev3 import Levenshtein
from itertools import combinations

mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo']
```

The following produces all possible pairs from the list, needed to compute the matrix

```
list(combinations(mylist,2))

[('foo', 'bar'),
 ('foo', 'baz'),
 ('foo', 'foo'),
 ('foo', 'foo'),
 ('bar', 'baz'),
 ('bar', 'foo'),
 ('bar', 'foo'),
 ('baz', 'foo'),
 ('baz', 'foo'),
 ('foo', 'foo')]
```

Then taking the distance for each pair can be done with the following:

```
def ld(a):
  return [Levenshtein.classic(*b) for b in combinations(a, 2)]


ld(mylist)
[3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0]
```

However, I am stuck on creating a matrix-like data frame in pandas - is there an eloquent solution to this in pandas?

```
       foo    bar   baz  foo   foo
1 foo   0     3     3    0     0
2 bar   3     0     1    3     3
3 baz   3     1     0    3     3
4 foo   0     3     3    0     0
5 foo   0     3     3    0     0
```

Comment: Your `mylist` has duplicated entries. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes that is intentional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try modify the function a bit so that we eliminate the calculation on duplicated entries:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def ld(a):
    u = set(a)
    return {b:Levenshtein.classic(*b) for b in product(u,u)}

dist = ld(mylist)

(pd.Series(list(dist.values()), pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dist.keys()))
   .unstack()
   .reindex(mylist)
   .reindex(mylist,axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
     foo  bar  baz  foo  foo
foo    0    3    3    0    0
bar    3    0    1    3    3
baz    3    1    0    3    3
foo    0    3    3    0    0
foo    0    3    3    0    0
```

Comment: I am getting `NameError: name 'dist' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, missed a cell when copy/paste. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the Levenshtein distance, I used *Levenshtein* module
(*pip install python-Levenshtein* required), used in pair with
*fuzzywuzzy*.

```
import Levenshtein as lv
```

Then, as we use *Numpy* functions, *mylist* must be converted
to a *Numpy* array:

```
lst = np.array(mylist)
```

And to compute the whole result, run:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(lv.distance)(lst[:, np.newaxis], lst[np.newaxis, :]),
    index=lst, columns=lst)
```

Details:

- `np.vectorize(lv.distance)` is a vectorized version of *lv.distance*
  function.
- `(lst[:, np.newaxis], lst[np.newaxis, :])` is a *numpythonic* idiom -
  a list of arguments "each with each" from *lst* array, for consecutive
  calls of the above function.
- Due to *Numpy* vectorization, the whole computation runs quickly,
  what can be seen especially on big arrays.
- `pd.DataFrame(...)` converts the above result (a *Numpy* array)
  to a DataFrame, with proper index and column names.
- If you want, use your original function instead of *lv.distance*.

The result is:

```
     foo  bar  baz  foo  foo
foo    0    3    3    0    0
bar    3    0    1    3    3
baz    3    1    0    3    3
foo    0    3    3    0    0
foo    0    3    3    0    0
```